# PyQGIS - can't changeAttributeValue - returns False

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

Part of my QGIS plugin is responsible for appending a new column to a vector layer and fill this column with values calculated earlier.

I'm able to append the column using

```
layerPoly = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(PolyName)[0]
layerPoly.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField(newName, QVariant.Double, "double", 10, 2)])
layerPoly.updateFields()
```

So far it works, creating a new field of a `double` type, length `10` and precision `2`.

Now starts the part of updating attributes of each feature:

```
columnid = layerPoly.fieldNameIndex(PolyName)

layerPoly.startEditing()

for feature in range(len(self.polygons)):
    # self.polygons is a list of features from layerPoly

    feat = self.polygons[feature]
    fid = feat.id()

    # self.y is a list of values that has length same as self.polygons
    item = round(self.y[feature],2)

    layerPoly.changeAttributeValue(fid, columnid, item)

layerPoly.commitChanges()
```

- `print type(fid)` returns type: `long` instead of `QgsFeatureId` as I think it should?
- `print type(columnid)` returns type: `int`
- `print type(item)` returns type: `float`

What causes the `changeAttributeValue` to be `False`? I thought it's `fid`'s type not `QgsFeatureID` but `int`, but compared to other codes I have seen on the Internet, this `fid`, `feat.id()` part is quite the same, so it shouldn't be an issue.

I'm using QGIS 2.8 and PyQt4==4.11.4.

Comment: hi, it's `self.polygons = [feature for feature in layerList_Poly[0].getFeatures()]`. self.polygons are a correct list, because I use this list to fill a qTableWidget somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Yes, way before, I also read the types just before this `changeAttributeValue`, I can also `print` contents of this list just a line above it

Comment: Have you checked the datatype of the variable item? The code all looks fine, I can only assume it's a datatype issue?

Comment: I'm sure I wrote it up here, but somehow it disappeared... The type is float (data are xxx.xx values). I edited the question.

Comment: I tried looping over features and so calling 'fresh' feature.id(), with same result. I couldn't make setFields work, documentation says it was introduced in Q 2.9, I'm using 2.8 and can't really have the newest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in `columnid` variable. Although it was of type `int`, the `columnid = layerPoly.fieldNameIndex(PolyName)` somehow was returning `-1` what was not a valid column id. The rest of code is fine.